# Unable to Hide NavBar when Swiped

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am attempting to hide my navBar when swiped and has implemented         `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true` at both `viewWillAppear()` and `viewDidLoad()` but the navBar remains unhidden. In my case, I have implemented a custom segmentedController below the navBar which toggles between two different tableViewControllers.

I am not sure if this is the reason why the navBar doesn't hide. My app looks like this, and the portion I want to hide is the 'Tickets' portion.[image]

My code as such:

```
class TicketsViewController: UIViewController {

    var upcomingTableViewController: UpcomingTableViewController!
    var pastTransactionTableViewController: PastTransactionsTableViewController!

    let segmentedControllerView: SegmentedController = {
        let sc = SegmentedController()
        sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sc.segmentedController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControlValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
        sc.segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        return sc
    }()

    let containerView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //These are the two tableViewControllers that are being toggled
        upcomingTableViewController = UpcomingTableViewController()
        pastTransactionTableViewController = PastTransactionsTableViewController()

        setupNavigationBar()
        setupViews()
    }

    @objc func segmentedControlValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        let segmentedControl = sender

        if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
          configureChildViewController(childController: upcomingTableViewController, onView: containerView)
        } else {
           configureChildViewController(childController: pastTransactionTableViewController, onView: containerView)
        }
    }

    func setupNavigationBar() {
        Helper.sharedInstance.setupNavigationBar(title: "Tickets", homeVC: self)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }

    func setupViews() {

        view.addSubview(segmentedControllerView)
        view.addSubview(containerView)

        segmentedControllerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        segmentedControllerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        segmentedControllerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        segmentedControllerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true

        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControllerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        containerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        configureChildViewController(childController: upcomingTableViewController, onView: containerView)

    }

    func configureChildViewController(childController: UIViewController, onView: UIView?) {
        var holderView = UIView()

        if let onView = onView {
            holderView = onView
        } else {
            holderView = self.view
        }

        addChildViewController(childController)
        holderView.addSubview(childController.view)
        constraintViewEqual(to: holderView, childControllerView: childController.view)
        childController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }


    func constraintViewEqual(to containerView: UIView, childControllerView: UIView) {
        childControllerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        childControllerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        childControllerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        childControllerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        childControllerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

The above code is my complete code for this ticketsViewController. Appreciate some advice why is the `hideBarsWhenSwipe` isn't hiding my navBar. Thanks.

Comment: Call this code `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true` inside of `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: @Mannopson I've tried this. It didnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resizing the element you have below to match the view controller height.

Comment: you mean the two tableViewControllers? or the segmentedControllerView?

Comment: @Koh you could use any of them, but the thing is that the total has to be the same height as the view controller, covering the full size.